# Python3: list index out of range

Tags: list, python-3.x, shuffle

```
def initDeck(n):
    cards = []  
    for i in range(n):
        cards.append(i + 1)
    return cards

def cutDeck(deck):
    decklength = len(deck)
    if((decklength % 2) != 0): #odds
        numTop = decklength//2
        numBot = numTop + 1
    else: #evens
        numTop = decklength//2
        numBot = decklength//2

    bottomDeck = []
    bottomDeck = deck[:(numBot)]

    topDeck = []
    topDeck = deck[(numBot):]

    return topDeck, bottomDeck

def shuffle(topDeck, bottomDeck):
    newDeck = []
    numcards = (len(topDeck)) + (len(bottomDeck))
    for g in range(numcards):
        newDeck.append(bottomDeck[g])
        newDeck.append(topDeck[g])

    return newDeck

#--------MAIN--------
n = int(input("How many cards do you want to shuffle? "))
numshuffles = int(input("How many times would you like to shuffle the deck? "))

deck = initDeck(n)

topDeck,bottomDeck = cutDeck(deck)

print(bottomDeck, '\n', topDeck, sep="")

while(numshuffles > 0):
    shuffledDeck = shuffle(topDeck, bottomDeck)
    numshuffles += -1
    print(shuffledDeck)
```

The program takes how many cards you want, how many times you want to shuffle, then riffle shuffles the deck. The problem is when I try to run it, it takes my two inputs then outputs two errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\etc", line 51, in <module>
    shuffledDeck = shuffle(topDeck, bottomDeck)
  File "C:\etc", line 35, in shuffle
    newDeck.append(bottomDeck[g])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong because it looks fine and makes sense to me. Any help would be very greatly appreciated as this is due at 8am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
numcards = (len(topDeck)) + (len(bottomDeck))
for g in range(numcards):
    newDeck.append(bottomDeck[g])
    newDeck.append(topDeck[g])
```

You are appending `bottomDeck[g]` and `topDeck[g]` to `newDeck` and `g` ranges from `0` to `len(bottomDeck) + len (topDeck)`. Means that at some point `g` becomes greater than `len(topDeck)` or `len(bottomDeck)`.

**EDIT:**
You can fix it like this.

```
for g in range(len(topDeck)):
    newDeck.append(bottomDeck[g])
    newDeck.append(topDeck[g])

# if total cards are odd, one card will be left in bottomDeck
if(len(topDeck) != len(bottomDeck)):
    newDeck.append(bottomDeck[-1])
```

Also you should again cut the deck after shuffle

```
while(numshuffles > 0):
    shuffledDeck = shuffle(topDeck, bottomDeck)
    numshuffles += -1
    print(shuffledDeck)
    topDeck,bottomDeck = cutDeck(shuffledDeck)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How do I fix the issue (sorry my mind is spacing)? I tried to add `- 1` after `(len(topDeck)) + (len(bottomDeck))` and that didn't work so I tried to add it into `range(numcards - 1)` and that didn't work either. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the fix! Now I have a problem where every time I shuffle it, it outputs the same thing. Is the problem that my `newDeck[]` is inside the funtion `shuffle()`? When I move it to `MAIN` it keeps extending the list. How can I fix this? Thanks a bunch for the help btw! I'd upvote you if I could.

Comment: Because your `topDeck` and `bottomDeck` are not changing. You can create new `topDeck` and `bottomDeck` from `shuffledDeck` but it will also repeat itself after `len(topDeck)` times. Also you shoud use `random` module to shuffle. If you can't upvote you can mark it as accepted since problem you posted is solved.

Comment: Well I have to do a riffle shuffle so I can't use random and I have to follow a format since it's for a class. I got it to work but it doesn't always output correctly. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
numcards = (len(topDeck)) + (len(bottomDeck))
    for g in range(numcards):
        newDeck.append(bottomDeck[g])
```

Your g goes up to the sum of lengths of topDeck and bottomDeck, hence becomes greater than len(bottomDeck).

Comment: Thanks for the response! How do I fix the issue (sorry my mind is spacing)? I tried to add `- 1` after `(len(topDeck)) + (len(bottomDeck))` and that didn't work so I tried to add it into `range(numcards - 1)` and that didn't work either. Thanks!